# Modified bug in questions

Tags: bug, questions, users

So in a question there is this "Modified" field when viewing from the main site. So if I edit a post or answer the question, it will say "Modified X mins ago UniKitty rep". So [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164165/how-do-i-fix-my-crashed-minecraft-world) question had one of those "Thanks!" answers, which I flagged. So the answer was deleted. Now to most of us it never existed. However, it still shows the deleted post's owner as the last modified person.

Here is the post in Arqade's homepage:
[image]

And here is the question:

[image]

See! There is no post by the user "Stimpy"

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yes, this is intentional and not a bug.

Comment: Didn't see that question. Sorry

Comment: Don't worry. Happens to all of us.